# How to hide the word (--wordpress) at browser tab from login page of WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to remove the word (-wordpress) from browser tab of login page but couldn't figure it out. Will be great if anyone could help here. 

As it shows in the screenshot, im trying to remove the highlighted in yellow. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to do this in your theme's functions.php file. Here are some modifications that you can use:

```
function my_login_logo_url() {
    return home_url();
}
add_filter( 'login_headerurl', 'my_login_logo_url' );

function my_login_logo_url_title() {
    return 'Your Site Name and Info';
}
add_filter( 'login_headertitle', 'my_login_logo_url_title' );
```

For more information, please refer to the WordPress Codex page [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form).

Answer (score 0):

I have to say I have found what you were looking for!

You'll have to head over to the 'wp-login' file and search for the $login_title attribute.

There you'll have to search for the word 'Wordpress' itself and erase it.
I fount mine on line 72.

You'll see the word as a string inside the parenthesis.

You'll have to go to the public_html and find the file there and change it.
I really hope It helped!

Good luck to anyone who reads it!

Comment: It is never a good idea to edit core wordpress files, always use a filter.